# pandas to_excel in version 0.15.2 not working for datetime objects

Tags: excel, datetime, pandas

A simple example of writing a `datetime` object to Excel is not working since I changed my pandas version to 0.15.2. Am I missing something?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame([datetime.datetime.today()])
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

Year, month and day are correctly displayed, for hour and so on I get zeros. If I write it to .csv the result is OK. Possibly a bug in 0.15.2?

Comment: Just checked and can confirm that there is the same problem ( with `to_excel`), although seconds are displayed correctly, only hour and minutes are `00:00:`. Also on 0.15.2, python 2.7.9

Comment: I see the correct behaviour both in 0.15.0 and 0.15.2. What versions of openpyxl (or other library used to write the excel) do you have?

Comment: I have openpyxl version 2.1.4 and I updated XlsxWriter to version 0.6.4. Still the problem remains. The datetime is not displayed correctly. Anyother idea?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9139

Comment: This is fixed in pandas master and will be released in the upcoming 0.16.

Answer (score 4):

As @joris commented some days ago, there is an issue for now with `to_excel` because of some `Timedelta` changes. see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9139

You can temporally fix this using `openpyxl` as XLSX writer engine using:

```
df.to_excel('test.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

With Pandas 0.16 this bug is now fixed and so you can do

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame([datetime.datetime.today()])
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

It will create an Excel file named `test.xlsx` like

```
  |    A
--+---------------------
1 |    0
2 |0   2015-07-13 10:27:34
```