# to_excel function does not transfer hour and minute info

Tags: python, pandas

I collect tweet data and the data includes time series that each tweet created at by hour, minute and second info.

```
def process_results(results):
id_list = [tweet.id for tweet in results]
data_set = pd.DataFrame(id_list, columns=["id"])

# Processing Tweet Data
data_set["created_at"] = [tweet.created_at for tweet in results]
```

When I execute below code, the result is as follow.

```
data_set = process_results(results)
print data_set.created_at

0    2015-07-11 22:13:32
1    2015-07-11 22:12:55
2    2015-07-11 22:04:52
3    2015-07-11 21:29:19
4    2015-07-11 21:27:14
```

After I execute below code; excel file only showing date and second info. Hour and minute info shows 00:00 in each columns. Could someone assist how to fix this.

```
data_set.to_excel("sample.xlsx")
```

Comment: Not sure why `to_excel` has this behavior, but if you don't specifically need `.xslx` format, `to_csv` treats datetimes well.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27548833/pandas-to-excel-in-version-0-15-2-not-working-for-datetime-objects) previous question for a workaround.  Also haven't verified, but may be fixed in newer `pandas` version.